# VBA Add All Range Variables to an Array

Tags: arrays, vba, variables, range

I have a VBA program where I set over 150 range variables on one tab.  I'm trying to figure out a way to clear the contents of all of the ranges associated with those variables, and so far the only way I can think of is to use the .ClearContents method for each variable one by one.  For example:

```
Sub rangeVariableQuestion()

Dim personnel As Range
Dim dateAndTime As Range
Dim companyName As Range
Dim reportDate As Range

''''''''''''''''''' + 150+ more variables

Set personnel = Range("Personnel")
Set dateAndTime = Range("Date")
Set companyName = Range("Company")
Set reportDate = Range("reportdate")

'''''''''''''''

personnel.ClearContents
dateAndTime.ClearContents
companyName.ClearContents
reportDate.ClearContents

'''''''''''''''''''    

End Sub
```

Is there a way I can all all my variables in the procedure to an array?  That way I can loop through each variable to clear the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I might go for an array of [Range objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) that I could loop through or use a [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) on the 150+ ranges.

```
Sub rangeVariableQuestion()

    Dim personnel As Range
    Dim dateAndTime As Range
    Dim companyName As Range
    Dim reportDate As Range
    Dim nukeThese As Range

    ''''''''''''''''''' + 150+ more variables

    Set personnel = Range("Personnel")
    Set dateAndTime = Range("Date")
    Set companyName = Range("Company")
    Set nukeThese = Union(personnel, dateAndTime, companyName)   '<~~ start off by setting to the union of three
    Set reportDate = Range("reportdate")
    Set nukeThese = Union(nukeThese, reportDate)                 '<~~ continue by setting union to self and other(s)

    '''''''''''''''

    'clear the unioned range    
    nukeThese.ClearContents
    'or just clear the union directly
    Union(personnel, dateAndTime, companyName, reportDate).ClearContents

    '''''''''''''''''''

End Sub
```

There are limits to the number of discontiguous ranges that can be addressed directly with the [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) in one command. You should be able to address up to 30 in one Union. After that, Union the original with 29 more.

Comment: Have you considered a 'Named Range' that encompasses all of the 150+ individual named ranges?